# How to find nearby major cities using google maps api given current location and 4hrs time.?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to know the list of major cities that can be reached in 4hrs(hours can vary) time from the current location of a user?
Is it possible using google maps?
Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: There's a few ways you might approach this. I tried a few but ran into roadblocks. I thought about combining the Places API with the Directions API, or perhaps the Geocoding with Directions. However there are limits on radius for Places API. You could geocode and find the current user state/country, then find major cities in that state and go from there.

Comment: "I tried a few but ran into roadblocks." - Loved this humorously apt comment! :). And it may be worth looking at OSM (OpenStreetMap) as an alternative: http://www.openstreetmap.org

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible. You may try to use  ["*Distance Matrix Requests*"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/). Use the  ["getDistanceMatrix"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DistanceMatrixService) that issues a distance matrix request.

Comment: This is just plain wrong (and a low quality answer anyway)...